# ubuntu 13.10 doesn't detect my android phone(Gingerbread)

Tags: usb, 13.10, drive

I recently upgraded my ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, after the upgrade when i try to mount my phone's disk (FAT fs),it doesn't show up as a drive ,the "dmesg" command shows "unable to enumerate USB on port 3" ,please help . ubuntu 13.04 detected the phone's SD card with hiccups.

Comment: Could you add the relevant lines of the dmesg instead of just telling us. The 10 lines before and the 10 lines after anything related to the event.

Answer (score 1):

I am suffering the same issue. I give you some dmesg lines. I hope it will help you to find a solution. Thanks.

[    5.291407] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.969011] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1163) terminated with status 1
[    8.296624] init: anacron main process (1010) killed by TERM signal
[   36.492057] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   36.624938] usb 1-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   36.625061] usb 1-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   36.740050] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   36.872972] usb 1-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   36.873094] usb 1-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   36.988056] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   37.013115] usb 1-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   37.013239] usb 1-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   37.128056] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[   37.149133] usb 1-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   37.149256] usb 1-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   37.152051] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[   37.468060] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[   37.627077] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   37.639082] usb 2-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   37.641080] usb 2-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   37.780056] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[   37.939063] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   37.951074] usb 2-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   37.953074] usb 2-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   38.120058] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[   38.145079] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   38.157078] usb 2-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   38.159076] usb 2-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   38.300053] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[   38.329080] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   38.341078] usb 2-1: Dual-Role OTG device on non-HNP port
[   38.343074] usb 2-1: can't set HNP mode: -32
[   38.344069] hub 2-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[  106.829572] wlan0: authenticate with 84:00:d2:d1:29:74
[  106.836996] wlan0: direct probe to 84:00:d2:d1:29:74 (try 1/3)
[  107.040066] wlan0: send auth to 84:00:d2:d1:29:74 (try 2/3)